# BulkEnvelopesApi Docusign request data format

Tags: ruby, docusignapi

I am stuck when using BulkEnvelopesApi rom Docusign API for Ruby. It keep on returning me this error:

> DocuSign_eSign::ApiError (Bad Request):

Edit: After @kiddorails suggestion to include debug = True, the error message is:

> {   "errorCode": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",   "message": "Value cannot be
>   null.\r\nParameter name: stream" }

I am using this gem: https://github.com/docusign/docusign-ruby-client

Is there anything wrong with the format of how I input the data?

Here's my code for reference.

```
  def self.send_env()
    self.auth # To initialize the @api_client

    t1 = DocuSign_eSign::TemplatesApi.new(@api_client)
    signer_placeholder ={"signers":[{"email":"bulk@recipient.com","name":"Bulk Recipient",
                                     "routingOrder":1,"recipientId":"1","roleName":"Fruit",
                                     "isBulkRecipient":"True"}]}
    t1.update_recipients(account_id=ENV["ACCOUNT_ID_LIVE"], template_id=ENV["TEMPLATE_ID_LIVE"], template_recipients=signer_placeholder)
    br = DocuSign_eSign::BulkRecipient.new(
        {
            "accessCode": '112233',
            "email": 'berry@gmail.com',
            "name": 'Berry',
            "rowNumber":1
        }
    )

    brr = DocuSign_eSign::BulkRecipientsRequest.new({"bulkRecipients": Array(br)})
    bea = DocuSign_eSign::BulkEnvelopesApi.new(@api_client)
    bea.update_recipients(account_id=ENV["ACCOUNT_ID_LIVE"], envelope_id=ENV["TEMPLATE_ID_LIVE"],
                      recipient_id="1",bulk_recipients_request=brr)
```

I am able to call other Docusign APIs using this similar data format. Only unable to work for BulkEnvelopesAPI.

I am thinking whether is there anything wrong with the source code for this BulkEnvelopesAPI function.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: inspect the full error message, that may tell you why the request is bad.

Comment: Hi @kiddorails, they didnt throw me any other error. I only have this though. The error comes from the last line of the code I've shown above.

Comment: while creating `@api_client`, pass `debugging = true` in config. It will enable http logging giving you insight of what's happening

Comment: @kiddorails Ah alright thanks. I have more visibility now!

Comment: Look in the request and response body it generates and confirm with docusign's api reference for bulkenvelopes; that should help you in fixing it. If it doesn't, you can update with relevant request and response body in question and let me know. (don't forget to tag in comment)

Comment: @kiddorails Hmm actually I have faced this error in Docusign API for Python before. And I went to edit the source code. However, I am not really sure what to edit for the source code in Ruby. I am still trying to edit it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173043/discussion-between-kiddorails-and-bread).

Answer (score 1):

With @kiddorails help, I've managed to solve it.

Here's the solution:

First, edit the source code in this format. Main idea is to change the Content-Type into 'text/csv', and input a string into the body.

```
def update_recipients_with_http_info(account_id, envelope_id, recipient_id, bulk_recipients_request)
      if @api_client.config.debugging
        @api_client.config.logger.debug "Calling API: BulkEnvelopesApi.update_recipients ..."
      end
      # verify the required parameter 'account_id' is set
      fail ArgumentError, "Missing the required parameter 'account_id' when calling BulkEnvelopesApi.update_recipients" if account_id.nil?
      # verify the required parameter 'envelope_id' is set
      fail ArgumentError, "Missing the required parameter 'envelope_id' when calling BulkEnvelopesApi.update_recipients" if envelope_id.nil?
      # verify the required parameter 'recipient_id' is set
      fail ArgumentError, "Missing the required parameter 'recipient_id' when calling BulkEnvelopesApi.update_recipients" if recipient_id.nil?
      # resource path
      local_var_path = "/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/bulk_recipients".sub('{format}','json').sub('{' + 'accountId' + '}', account_id.to_s).sub('{' + 'envelopeId' + '}', envelope_id.to_s).sub('{' + 'recipientId' + '}', recipient_id.to_s)

      # query parameters
      query_params = {}

      # header parameters
      header_params = {}
      # HTTP header 'Accept' (if needed)
      header_params['Accept'] = @api_client.select_header_accept(['application/json'])
      header_params['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
      # form parameters
      form_params = {}

      # http body (model)
      # post_body = @api_client.object_to_http_body(bulk_recipients_request)
      # puts bulk_recipients_request
      # post_body = body_params
      auth_names = []
      data, status_code, headers = @api_client.call_api(:PUT, local_var_path,
        :header_params => header_params,
        :query_params => query_params,
        :form_params => form_params,
        :body => bulk_recipients_request,
        :auth_names => auth_names,
        :return_type => 'BulkRecipientsSummaryResponse')
      if @api_client.config.debugging
        @api_client.config.logger.debug "API called: BulkEnvelopesApi#update_recipients\nData: #{data.inspect}\nStatus code: #{status_code}\nHeaders: #{headers}"
      end
      return data, status_code, headers
    end
  end
```

Secondly, set bulk_recipients_request to be a string (with newlines for each row of data)

```
"rowNumber,email,name,Accesscode\n"+"1,berry@gmail.com,Berry,11223\n"
```